# Persistent Cart for Guest Customers in Magento 1x

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, persistent

Is there any option to save cart data in cookies (persistent cart) for guest customers?

I need to save it for 1 year.

**For registered customers, I'm able to enable it from System > Customers > Persistent Shopping Cart.**

Answer (score 1):

yes you can set it, you just have to set the cookie path.

You can try following.

**Go to system->configuration->web (under general tab) -> session cookie management.**

Give cookie path as / and mention cookie lifetime.

Please give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Not working for me as i have set / in cookie path

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I need to add functionality of "Persistent Shopping Cart" for guest user for 24 hrs.
Can someone give me a direction how can I do that in magento 1.

**Go to system->configuration->web (under general tab) -> session cookie management.**
This setting works only when guest is logged user otherwise not.

Thanks everyone in advance!